# SQL newbie: execution order of subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Warning:** This is a soft question, where you'll be answering to someone who has just started teaching himself `SQL` from the ground up. I haven't gotten my database software set up yet, so I can't provide tables to run queries against. Some patience required.

Warnings aside, I'm experimenting with basic `SQL` but I'm having a little bit of a rough time getting a clear answer about the inner workings of subqueries and their execution order within my query.

Let us say my query looks something like shit:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable

WHERE someFirstValue = someSecondValue

AND EXISTS (

  SELECT * FROM someOtherTable

  WHERE someTable.someFirstValue = someOtherTable.someThirdValue
  )

;
```

The reason I'm here, is because I don't think I understand fully what is going on in this query.

Now I don't want to seem lazy, so I'm not going to ask you guys to "tell me what's going on here", so instead, I'll provide my own theory first:

1. The first row in `someTable` is checked so see if `someFirstValue` is the same as `someSecondValue` in that row.
2. If it isn't, it goes onto the second row and checks it too. It continues like this until a row passes this little inspection.
3. If a row does pass, it opens up a new query. If the table produced by this query contains even a single row, it returns `TRUE`, but if it's empty it returns `FALSE`.

My theory ends here, and my confusion begins.

Will this inner query now compare only the rows that passed the first `WHERE`? Or will it check all the items `someTable` and `someOtherTable`?

Rephrased; will only the rows that passed the first `WHERE` be compared in the `someTable.someFirstValue = someOtherTable.someThirdValue` subquery?

Or will the subquery compare all the elements from `someTable` to all the elements in `someOtherTable` regardless of which passed the first `WHERE` and which didn't?

**UPDATE:** Assume I'm using MySQL 5.5.32. If that matters.

Comment: Optimizer is a complex toy. So it highly depend on a multiple factors (which includes mysql version number) and in some cases it may even rewrite a query to become a `JOIN` then change the order of them

Comment: S-so people's conclusion is... we don't know?

Comment: the conclusion is: you cannot tell how exactly optimizer will execute the given query unless you take into account million different factors (which include - mysql configuration, hardware, mysql version, statistics, database schema, ...). In one case the plan may look like A thing, in another - like something completely different.

Comment: It would be best that you convert this query to an equivalent `JOIN` query by yourself. The optimizer will have better chances of optimizing the query further.

Comment: *"Rephrased; will only the rows that passed the first WHERE be compared in the be compared in the subquery?"* - Absolutely, unless the query optimizer concludes that doing it differently would be faster. That's as close to an answer as you will get with questions like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that SQL is a descriptive language that describes the result set being produced from a query.  It does not specify how the query is going to be run.

In your case the query has several options on how it might run, depending on the database engine, what the tables look like, and indexes.  The query itself:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM someTable t
WHERE t.someFirstValue = t.someSecondValue AND
      EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM someOtherTable t2
              WHERE t.someFirstValue = t2.someThirdValue
             );
```

Says:  "Get me all columns from `SomeTable` where `someFirstValue = someSecondValue` and there is a corresponding row in `someOtherTable` where that's table column `someThirdValue` is the same as `someFirstValue`".

One possible way to approach this query would be to scan `someTable` and first check for the first condition.  When the two columns match, then look up `someFirstValue` in an index on `someOtherTable(someThirdValue)` and keep the row if the values match.  As I say, this is one approach, and there are others.